# Popup video keeps playing in background after closing the popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, html5-video

I have a button that when clicked, pops up a video that can played.
The problem is that if you close the popup while the video is playing, closing the popup does not stop the video, but it keeps playing in background.

```
<div>
    <a id="click-me">Click Me</a>
</div>

<div id="popup-mpdal" style="display:none;">
    <div class="">
        <video id="videoplayer" controls poster='<?php echo $block->getUrl("pub/media/video/")?>whats-your-story.png'>
            <source src='<?php echo $block->getUrl("pub/media/video/")?>this-is-chris-saint-long-version.mp4' type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-mpdal'));
            $("#click-me").on('click',function(){ 
                $("#popup-mpdal").modal("openModal");
            });

        }
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear as to what's going on here, but when the modal is being closed you aren't doing anything to either pause or reset the video. Here's a pretty simple way to stop it.

```
 var video = document.getElementById("videoplayer");
 function pauseVideo(){
      video.pause();
 }
```

Now if you call `pauseVideo()` inside the click handler for your buttons it should stop the video.